# Detect change in an input field when selecting value from a box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect a change in the input field when i select a value from the box like in the picture  below.

[image: <code>Selecting value from a box</code>]

**html:**

```
<input type="text" class="AgeChangeInput" id="range"/>
```

**js:(not working)**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert("Hello");
    $("#range").bind('input', function()
    {
        alert("done");
    });
});
</script>
```

I also tried `live` `on` functions but they didn;t work too.

Comment: Which plugin do you use for input selection?

Comment: if possible add a jsfiddle

Comment: http://tutorialzine.com/2013/01/charts-jquery-ajax/ i am using this.

Comment: why .bind('input'...), you mean .bind('change',... ) probably?

Comment: @user3400389 No, you're using this: https://github.com/tylerwolff/bootstrap-daterangepicker

Comment: yes the plugin is this one. @RGraham

Comment: is it some where near check out ->>>> http://jsfiddle.net/vr8z3/

Comment: No event is triggered on an input field when its value is changed by JS from another field. You need to bind a handler to the other element.

Comment: @user3127499 no change() is not working.

Comment: @Barmar how should i do that.provide an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this code

**changeDate** - This event is fired when the date is changed.

```
 $('#range').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
      //example of condition
      if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
       //make action here
        alert('Here');
      }
});
```

Comment: i will reply back soon after testing this.

Comment: it popup the datepicker when i click the input field.

Comment: Use a condition to check if the date has been changed :) or you can use  onSelect: function(dateText) {...}

Answer (score 3):

Your date selection box should fire a change event, then you only need to capture it:

```
$(function () {
    $('#range').change(function () {
        ...
    });
});
```

If the selection box doesn't fire the event, you'll need to trick the dom. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Asuming your selection box opens on input click
    $('#range').click(function () {
        $('.special-box-class').click(fireRangeEvent);
    });

    // Now the firing function
    function fireRangeEvent() {
        ...
    }
});
```

Hope it works

Comment: yep that is another way

Comment: this is working fine with one problem. when i click on the box and choose the value alert pop up. now again when i click and choose another value now this time alert() popup two times

Comment: function fireRangeEvent()
    {
        alert("dsds");
    }